# ArrayList - javaIllegalArugmentException

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Im making a tic-tac-toe game and don't ask why but my computer players strategy is to go vertically down on the last column. If its intercepted it will then just go and be placed in random places. However, after a few games i get "bound must be positive at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)". Im not sure whats wrong with my arraylist as it stores the free squares left on the board. The board is 4x4. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package noughtsAndCrossesV3;

import ncErrors.outOfRangeError;
import noughtsAndCrossesV3.NCGridV3.SquareStatus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class MyComputerPlayer extends GenericPlayer implements NCPlayer {

    Random theGenerator;

    public MyComputerPlayer()
    {
        super();        // no further initialisation required
        theGenerator = new Random();
    }


    @Override
    public GridCoordinate getNextMove(NCGridV3 currentGrid){
        int Row;
        int Col;
        GridCoordinate theSquare = null;
        ArrayList<GridCoordinate> freeSquares = new ArrayList<GridCoordinate>();
        int randomSelection;


        for (Row = 0; (theSquare == null) && (Row < currentGrid.getGridRowDimension()); Row++){
            for (Col = 0; (theSquare == null) && (Col < currentGrid.getGridColDimension()); Col++){


                try{

                    if(currentGrid.getSquareStatus(Row,Col)==NCGridV3.SquareStatus.EMPTY){
                        freeSquares.add(new GridCoordinate(Row, Col));
                        }


                if(currentGrid.getSquareStatus(Row, 3)==NCGridV3.SquareStatus.EMPTY){
                        theSquare = new GridCoordinate(Row, 3);
                        }

                if(currentGrid.getSquareStatus(Row,3)==NCGridV3.SquareStatus.NOUGHT){
                        randomSelection = theGenerator.nextInt(freeSquares.size());
                        return freeSquares.get(randomSelection);
                        }

                    }

                catch (outOfRangeError e){
                    }

            }
        }
        return theSquare; 

    }


}
```

Comment: You're passing in zero. Your list must be empty.

Comment: That exception will happen once you've got a `NOUGHT` or a `CROSS` in the (0, 0) position and a `NOUGHT` in the `(0, 3)` position.

Comment: Oh thanks but why would that be?